# Best model for Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 with one Server and multiple Clients

Tags: sql, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I have designed 3 windows services as listed below:

1. ClientProvisioning
2. ServerProvisioning
3. DataSyncServerClient

Now as I mentioned above, I have one master server at Cloud and many clients (10-15).
I wold like to know the best way to implement the Syncprocess to sync all clients and cloud db ib bi-directional.

I was thinking of a model as explained below:

1. Run clientProvisioning Windows Service at each client once.
2. Then Run DataSyncServerClient Windows Service at certain interval to sync the data between each client and cloud.

Repeat above two steps for each client. And `ServerProvisioning` will be run at cloud once.

Is this a good idea, or is there any better solution to achieve this? All Clients and Cloud have the same DB Schema.

Comment: why create three separate windows service? before synching, just check if the database is provision or not, if not, provision, then sync.

Comment: @JuneT -- Its not just once. I need to Schedule the sync process for all the clients.Hence I can just run the provisioning at each client once and then I am asking about whether to run the Sync between client and server at each client or any other way?

Comment: which one is not once? can your cloud service connect to your client? most likely not, so you should initiate the sync from the client.

Comment: The Sync process is not once.So you are saying whatever I have planned initially is the right one. As I explained above,run the Sync process at each client place

Comment: of course a sync is not once, otherwise, it's just copying :) what am questioning is why separate the provisioning service from the sync service. if the database is not provisioned and you sync, you get an error. so why not check if the database is provisioned before doing the sync.

Comment: @JuneT: Yeah I can combine Provisioning and Sync. Suppose I run the Sync process at cloud server, how will I handle all the cliennts sync at different timings? Also could you please tell me using MS Sync Framework 2.1 will restrict on version of sql server on either side? I mean is there any restrictions on using sql server versions?

Comment: @JuneT - Colud you please let me know what is the best way to modify the Scope. As If I want to add more tables to sync in future,what is the easiest way to do it? pls suggest

Comment: min SQL Server version supported is SQL 2005 SP2

Comment: Sync Fx doesnt support modifying sync scope definitions. if you're adding new tables, why not just add a new scope for the new tables?

Comment: @JUneT -- If I add new scope for new set of tables,then is Syncprocess will handle multiple Scopes at once? Or I need to design a new Syncprocess for each scope?

Comment: you can only sync one scope at a time. there's no stopping you having different threads synching though.

Comment: Ok JuneT thanks a lot for the clarifications.I really appreciate your help on this.